# How do I delete my account?

Tags: discussion

I signed up by mistake but do not wish to participate. How can I delete my account?

Comment: Hello Berthalina, I am sorry to hear your experience was so bad. We are very particular about keeping all posts on the site civil, so I had to edit your question a lot - something which is not done in other cases. As for commenting, if signing up was sufficient to comment, we would be suffocating in messages left by spam bots who sign up automatically. This is why we ask for a bit of reputation before commenting. If you discovered a wrong link somewhere, you can suggest an edit to the post, even without signing up, and somebody will approve the edit.

Answer (score 3):

We are part of a larger network of sites, so account deletion is documented for all sites at once. It is explained here: [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

To summarize, there are two ways to delete your account. The first one is only available for very new users with almost no participation. In this case, you will see a "Delete" link on your user page under "edit profile and settings".

If you cannot find the link, or if you have already posted much content or voted, you need to request deletion from the contact form, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/contact. In the dropdown, choose "I need to delete my account". A team member will manually delete your account soon.